# Combine `if` inside another `if` statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have the following `if` statement:

```
if( @items.name.present? && @items.value.present?)
```

I would like to add a check for `@items.price.blank? if @items_table[:check_price]` to this `if` statement. So my final if statement would check for all three conditions using `&&` if my model had `[:check_price]`; otherwise it will only check for the two conditions written.

Comment: Are you having a problem doing this?

Comment: Yes i am not sure how to do this. I tried if( @items.name.present? && @items.value.present? && @items.price.blank? if @items_table[:check_price]), but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: As a general practice, you might consider using `@items_table.key?(:check_price)` (or `has_key?`) rather than  `@items_table[:check_price]`, as it works with hashes that have keys equal to `nil`.  You might find it reads better as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to be a little bit more creative about how you write your condition:

```
if @items.name.present? && @items.value.present? && 
   (!@items_table[:check_price] || @items.price.blank?)
```

Do you see why that works?

By writing it this way, you're basically saying "if the name is present and the value is present and {either I'm not supposed to check the price, or the price is blank}, then..." Which is equivalent to what you asked.

Comment: works great, thanks. I didn't even think to use the or operator that way but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby uses lazy evaluation, therefore simply move the condition at the beginning to skip the other checks in case of false.

```
if @items_table[:check_price] && @items.name.present? && @items.value.present? && @items.price.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do or what problem you are having doing it. But I think simply this will actually do what you want -- in ruby '&&' is "short circuit", meaning later conditions won't even evaluate if earlier ones evaluate to falsy.

```
if( @items.name.present? && @items.value.present? && @items_table[:check_price])
```

If you really want two nested if's, it works like this:

```
    if( @items.name.present? && @items.value.present?)
      if @items_table[:check_price]
         # stuff
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use ENGLISH!, that's always my preferable programming language :-)

```
    name_and_value_valid?(@items) && price_valid?(@items, @items_table)

    def name_and_value_valid?(items)
       items.name.present? && items.value.present?
    end

    def price_valid?(items, items_table)
      items.price.blank? if items_table[:check_price]
    end
```